Is it a bad idea to run a replacement water line under a water drainage pipe?
I just dug a massive moat in my yard which I intend to install a drainage pipe in to set up drainage for my house. My inlet water line is probably galvanized and very old. I would like to replace it. Is there any reason why -- having already dug most of the route up already, that I shouldn't install a new water line while I'm doing this?
Put down a run of 2 inch schedule 80 under the drain line?

Will it be below the local frost line?

@crip659 I'm in Houston. I believe the frost line is 14,283 feet.

Step one: find the incoming water line and determine its type and condition. "Probably" in not a very good metric.

The frost line in Texas will be small, not large.  Google suggests one foot (twelve inches).

@mdfst13 I think you may have misunderstood Evan's comment—I believe he was giving an elevation, not a depth. :)

Besides the two lines going to and from different places, I wouldn't advise it since replacing or repairing one then means you either have to dig up the other or risk damaging it.
Pretty sure it's allowed by code, but there are separation requirements. like backfill the water then put the sewer over it.
Seems to me the costs here are running the water pipe, not digging the trench, especially if the Ditch Witch is already on site.

The Ditch Witch was me with a drain spade
